# How to proceed now , development is done !

Tags: advertising, standards, marketing

The project I was working/coding on from last couple of months is done from a development point of view. The project is a lightweight desktop video streaming application in Adobe Air. I also put up a website to publish it:

`http://awesome.fm/client`

I am less experience in marketing or spreading products. Can you guys just give me ideas on how to proceed from here?

What I want to know is, how do real startup owners spread the product they make?

Whatsoever, any opinion will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try asking on http://startups.com/ - their website runs the same software this site does so the experience will be familiar for you, and they have guys there that know a hell of a lot about this sort of stuff.

Comment: Be aware that the stackexchange 2.0 startups site should be in closed beta soon as well http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business

Comment: http://answers.onstartups.com just entered public beta.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays it's all about the social networking. Twitter, facebook, google buzz, linkedin, etc. Put out some youtube videos showing off your product, post those to twitter, facebook, etc and use google-analytics to see where you're hitting and if you're hitting your market. You need to define your market as well. Are you going for techies, or tweens or everyone? It's all about figuring out who your demographic is and then making your product seem palatable to that group.

I agree with farseeker though. This doesn't seem web development related, more marketing related, so you may get some better answers there.