# How to bring visitors to a new website?

Tags: traffic, marketing, website-promotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to start driving traffic to a new website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/what-are-the-best-ways-to-start-driving-traffic-to-a-new-website)

I am more of a programmer than an SEO expert. 
Whenever I develop a new website, no matter how good or bad it is, after the most of the development work is over, the ultimate question remains, how to bring visitors to a new website, how to let the world know of its existence. Search Engines are of no use, because they only help after visitors start coming to website.

Comment: FYI, search engines and website traffic have no direct correlation. It is very common to get traffic from search engines without having much traffic to your site. It worked for my personal site for sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Search Engines are of no use, because
>   they only help after visitors start
>   coming to website.

This is not true. Search engines will index your site even if you got no real visit. The problem is: you will probably face a strong competition that will put you some pages behind.

As your site get connected with others (other good sites linking to you) and you publish good quality content, you will start appearing in front.

Now the main point: **NEVER** make your online strategy your unique marketing strategy. Other medias are also important when telling a new brand to the world.