# How can I increase my web site visitor?

Tags: web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to start driving traffic to a new website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/what-are-the-best-ways-to-start-driving-traffic-to-a-new-website)

I have a web site that www.viewbd.com
But i have not enough visitor how can i increase my visitor or traffic

Answer (score 3):

1. Get a sitemap - I see you're using wordpress so I suggest looking at [Google XML Sitemap Generator](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/)
2. Put a link in your email/forum signature
3. [Don't be a content farm](http://www.bdtips.com/Article_Body.php?Main_Category_ID=23&Article_ID=5186). Google doesn't like content farms that duplicate content. Or if someone else is a content farm, have a quiet word with them.

Those are a couple of points.