# Increasing traffic for music blog

Tags: traffic, blog, website-promotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I own a music blog with some articles and of course youtube iframes and mp3 listening plugins. I get traffic from google and some not very popular site (I don't mention it because you can think it's a SPAM) where I post links with pictures to my posts. Any ideas to get more traffic for this kind of blog? I know about Myspace, blog directories, video sharing sites, same niche blogs and relevant forums. Anything I'm missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the answers to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/what-are-the-best-ways-to-start-driving-traffic-to-a-new-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your music blog was posting specific types of music for example club remixes of popular songs. You may want to find related blogs and post meaningful comments and link to your site. But again meaningful not spam comments. Don't use your website name in place of your name on wordpress sites user your real name link to your site when available and be genuine with your comments.

Find music related forums, spend a few weeks or months posting and contributing to build up reputation, make sure you are not only replying to threads but creating new threads which people are replying to. Once you have built up some reputation and posts, see what the forum rules are on signature links and if it's ok create one to your blog.

Keep up to date with music in Google News, and when you see a news article relevant to your blog. Read the article comment and link back to your website if possible.

Contact related blog owners, friends etc ask if they will link to your blog.

You need dofollow links from relevant quality web pages to rank higher in the organics. For traffic you just need to build a following.